# Remove ImageListView Item by using Filename

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.drawing

I have added some images to [ImageListView](http://oozcitak.github.io/imagelistview/index.html).I need to remove a file using the filename.
You can remove the selected item using

```
 imageListView1.Items.Remove(imageListView1.SelectedItems[0]);
```

How can i remove an item using the filename?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
using System.Linq;

bool removed = false;

foreach ( var item in imageListView1.Items.ToList() )
  if ( item.FileName == filenameToFind )
  {
    imageListView1.Items.Remove(item);
    removed = true;
    break;  // with a break it will only remove the first found else all duplicates
  }
```

Comment: isnt there a better approach than to iterate ?

Comment: I don't know this library and I did not see a Remove by filename in the code. What is the problem with the loop?

Comment: If there is a way remove items by filename.. the loop would be a waste of time and resources..

Comment: You can download the code of the control [here](https://github.com/oozcitak/imagelistview) to study the code.